# Editing Outlook.MailItem's RTFBody with C#

Tags: c#, outlook, rtf

I'm trying to append a string to an outgoing Outlook.MailItem. In the send event handler I have:

```
switch (mailItem.BodyFormat) {
    case Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText:
        byte[] mailItemBytes = mailItem.RTFBody as byte[];
        System.Text.Encoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        string RTF = encoding.GetString(mailItemBytes);
        RTF += "my string";
        byte[] moreMailItemBytes = encoding.GetBytes(RTF);
        mailItem.RTFBody = moreMailItemBytes;
        break;
    // ...
}
```

but the received email does not contain my string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RTF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140277%28v=office.10%29.aspx) is a pretty elaborate format for files and isn't going to be as easy as concatenating a string. You may try using the [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) control and importing the data there first, adding text to it, then re-grabbing the formatted value back. A bit clunky, but a lot easier than parsing an RTF file.

As an alternative, you may be able to find a library that parses and works with RTF, but that means a dependency for your application and most likely another DLL to include in the release.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old and has green check already but after searching for similar issues I found a page that gives a good answer for how to modify the RTF body in an outlook project using the Word.Document object model. https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=12738

Basically you treat the text a word doc and forget about working with RTF all together. You will need to add reference of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to your project first.

then add using to your project

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

then add your code

```
Word.Document doc = Inspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;

//text body
string text = doc.Content.Text;

//end of file
int endOfFile = (text.Length) > 0 ? text.Length - 1 : 0; 

//Select the point to add or modify text
Word.Range myRange = doc.Range(endOfFile, endOfFile);

//add your text to end of file
myRange.InsertAfter("my string");
```